# Execute javascript when redirect finishes

Tags: javascript, redirect, sencha-touch

At some point of a Javascript, I need to redirect to another page. I do it like this.

```
window.location.href='http://localhost:3000/m/debug';
```

And then, when that page finishes loaded, I need to access the window.Ext object of this new page. I have try to do the following, but it does not work.

```
window.onload = function(){alert(typeof window.Ext);}; // returns 'undefined'
window.location.href='http://localhost:3000/m/debug#settings';
```

Or

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert(typeof window.Ext); },5000); // is never called
window.location.href='http://localhost:3000/m/debug#settings';
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you set `window.location.href` the browser navigates away from the current page - **no** further JavaScript will be executed ... not even functions set using `setTimeout/setInterval`

If you want to execute JavaScript on the target page you need to add update the target page with your JavaScript !

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "you need to add update the target page with your JavaScript" ??

Comment: @TDeBailleul what I mean is ... if you want to execute JavaScript on a page - you need the JavaScript to be on that page - so you would need to change the target page (ie what ever url you navigate to) and add your code to that page .. so in your case - add the code you want to execute when the page `http://localhost:3000/m/debug` has loaded to the page `http://localhost:3000/m/debug`